# Tablesorter: Filtering and Ajax Pager Issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I am noticing odd behavior with `tablesorter` when the filter widget and pager addon are enabled. Here's the scenario:

I have a table with a total of 366 entries that I have applied the filter widget and pager addon to. Below is a snippet of the table data set that I am operating on.

[image: tablesorted_table]

Say for example that I filter the results by Register `BIN_d_USE_RBLKS\s` (where \s is simply denoting that I have included a white space char in the search)...

As seen in the screen shot below, the filtered results that are displayed do not change from the previously displayed results. Yet the pager was accurately updated (as seen in the upper left hand corner) with the Ajax query indicating that there were no results matching those search parameters.

[image: filtered_table]

Ideally the filtered search would return an empty set, yet it is not. How can I fix this? Is there a setting I am missing?

**Update 1**

I understand that the pager sets both the core `config.serverSideSorting` option and the `filter_serversideFiltering` widget option to true. This means that server is responsible for sorting the data based on the filter criteria that pager passes to the server. Below is a snippet of the PHP server side code that is being used to generate the Ajax response.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$size = $_GET['size'];
$design_filter = stripslashes($_GET['filter'][0]);
$reg_filter = stripslashes($_GET['filter'][1]);

// row entry offset.
$offset = $page*$size;

try {
    $con = new PDO( "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $passwd);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // If the filter is surrounded in quotes, treat it literally. Otherwise,
    // match it as a substring. 
    $quote_regex = '/^([\"\']).*\1$/m';
    $literal_design = preg_match($quote_regex, $design_filter);
    $literal_reg = preg_match($quote_regex, $reg_filter);

// both filters specify literal interpretation
if ($literal_design && $literal_reg)
{
    SELECT SOMETHING
}

// only treat design filter as a literal
if ($literal_design && !$literal_reg)
{
    SELECT SOMETHING
}

// only treat register filter as a literal
if (!$literal_design && $literal_reg)
{
    SELECT SOMETHING
}

// no filters are literals
if (!$literal_design && !$literal_reg)
{
    SELECT SOMETHING
}

// get the page and size limited entries
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$result = $con->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetch();
$total_rows = $result['FOUND_ROWS()'];


$data_payload = array("total_rows" => $total_rows, "headers" => array("Design", "Register"), "rows" => array());
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $reg_rule = array("Design" => $row['design_id'], "Register" => $row['data_register']);
    array_push($data_payload['rows'], $reg_rule);
}

$json_payload = json_encode($data_payload);
echo $json_payload;
```

I have also verified with manual inspection of the SQL queries that the filters limit the returned response from the database appropriately. I have filtering working well, all except the case that I present above.

**UPDATE 2**

If no data matches a search filter, the server should not respond with a `rows` field in the JSON.

```
// get the page and size limited entries
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$result = $con->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetch();
$total_rows = $result['FOUND_ROWS()'];

if ($total_rows == 0)
{
    $data_payload = array("total_rows" => $total_rows, "headers" => array("Design", "Register"));
    echo json_encode($data_payload);
} else {
    $data_payload = array("total_rows" => $total_rows, "headers" => array("Design", "Register"), "rows" => array());
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $reg_rule = array("Design" => $row['design_id'], "Register" => $row['data_register']);
        array_push($data_payload['rows'], $reg_rule);
    }

    $json_payload = json_encode($data_payload);
    echo $json_payload;
}
```

This ensures that the filter widget will clear the table when a search doesn't have a matching entry in the database server side. I didn't see this anywhere in the documentation, and I highly recommend adding this somewhere. This would have saved me hours of my time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no data matches a search filter, the server should not respond with a `rows` field in the JSON.

```
// get the page and size limited entries
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

$result = $con->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetch();
$total_rows = $result['FOUND_ROWS()'];

if ($total_rows == 0)
{
    $data_payload = array("total_rows" => $total_rows, "headers" => array("Design", "Register"));
    echo json_encode($data_payload);
} else {
    $data_payload = array("total_rows" => $total_rows, "headers" => array("Design", "Register"), "rows" => array());
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $reg_rule = array("Design" => $row['design_id'], "Register" => $row['data_register']);
        array_push($data_payload['rows'], $reg_rule);
    }

    $json_payload = json_encode($data_payload);
    echo $json_payload;
}
```

This ensures that the filter widget will clear the table when a search doesn't have a matching entry in the database server side. I didn't see this anywhere in the documentation, and I highly recommend adding this somewhere. This would have saved me hours of my time.

Answer (score 0):

When using the pager with ajax, the pager sets both the core [`config.serverSideSorting` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#serversidesorting) and the [`filter_serversideFiltering` widget option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-serversidefiltering) to `true` ([src](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js#L1025-L1027)) because there is no way for the client side to perform these functions without output from the server, or having the entire database on the client side, but then you wouldn't need ajax.

The server should be sorting the database and using the filter(s) provided by the ajax request and return the results to the pager ajax functions for display.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I appreciate it. I have updated my original post with more details that should provide you with some insight as to what is happening. The filtering is working almost perfectly, but the case I presented above is still an issue.

Comment: See **Update 2** above.

Comment: Hmm, I actually think that's a bug that pops up when `totalRows` is zero... I'll fix it here shortly.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for doing that. 

In the meantime, if now rows were returned from the database query, then discarding the `rows` field in the Ajax response suffices.